# DynamicProgramming dice sum number of ways

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given n dice each with m faces, numbered from 1 to m, find the number of ways to get sum X. X is the summation of values on each face when all the dice are thrown.
4+3 and 3+4 should be treated same.
dont consider different permutations.
Example for n=2 , m =6 and X = 7
No of ways should be 3 ( 1,6  and 2,5 and 3,4)

Comment: Not a hard problem. But I think you should give some examples about your problem...

Comment: @Sayakiss Thanks , added an example

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

I write a short Python code for you:

```
d = {}


def f(n, m, x):
    if n == 0 and x == 0:
        return 1
    if n < 0 or m == 0 or x < 0:
        return 0
    if d.get((n, m, x)) is not None:
        return d[(n, m, x)]
    ret = f(n - 1, m, x - m) + f(n, m - 1, x)
    d[(n, m, x)] = ret
    return ret


print f(2, 6, 7) #return 3, as your example
print f(3, 6, 7) #return 4, (2 2 3), (1 3 3), (1 2 4), (1 1 5)
```

A simple explanation:

```
f(n, m, x) = the ways of now we have n dices, and now the dice numbered from 1 to m to achieve sum x.
```

And

```
f(n, m, x) = f(n - 1, m, x - m) + f(n, m - 1, x)
```

Then

```
f(n - 1, m, x - m): throw a dice and it must be number m.
f(n, m - 1, x): don't throw a dice, and we let the dice number decrease 1(so we can't throw a dice with number m now, it could be m-1 as most)
```

Why we must throw a dice with number m? Oh, in that way, we could get a solution which is different from others(I mean avoid count `3+4` and `4+3` as different solutions).

Summarize the above with memorization(if you have no idea about memorization, you may learn some basic things about dynamic programming), we come to solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps !

```
import itertools

face = 6
throw = 3
sum_ = 12

combinations = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(list(range(1,face+1)), throw)
a = []
c = 0
for i in combinations:
    if sum(i) == sum_ :
        c = c +1
        for j in itertools.permutations(i):
            if j not in a:
                a.append(j)
print("With repetitions",len(a))
print("Without repetitions",c)
```